# Is it OK to share observables between multiple clients using SSE?

Tags: java, rxjs, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have a service (ServiceA) with an endpoint to which client can subscribe and after subscription, this service produces data continuously using server sent events.

If this is important, I am using Project Reactor with Java.

It may be important, so I'll explain what this endpoint does. Every 15 seconds it fetches data from another service (ServiceB), checks if there were some changes with data that it fetched 15 seconds ago and if there were, it prouces a new event with this data, if there were no changes, it does not send anything (so the payload to the client is as small as possible).

Now, this application can have multiple clients connected at once and they all ask for the same data - it is not filtered by the user etc.

Is it sensible that this observable producing the output is shared between multiple clients?

Of course it would save us a lot of unnecessary calls to the ServiceB, but I wonder if there are any counterindications to this approach - it is the first time I am writing reactive program on the backend (coming from the RxJS) and I don't know if this would cause any concurrency problems or any other sort of problems.

The other benefit I can see is that a new client connecting would immediately be served the last received data from the ServiceB (it usually takes about 4s per call to retrieve this data).

I also wonder if it would be possible that this observable is calling the ServiceB only if there are some subscribers - i.e. until there is at least one subscriber, call the service, if there are no subscribers stop calling it, when a new subscriber subscribes call it again but first fetch the client the last fetched data (no matter how old or stale it may be).

Comment: it is not clear if ServiceA is located in the same JVM instance or accessible via network only. And how "server sent events" work.

Comment: ServiceB is accessible via network only. Server Sent Events are basically an infinite flux of data. It will be streamed every 15s as long as the connection with the client persists.

Answer (score 0):

your SSE source can perfectly be shared using the following pattern:

```
source.publish().refCount();
```

Note that you need to store the return value of that call and return that same instance to subsequent callers in order for the sharing to occur.

Once all subscribers unsubscribe, `refCount` will also cancel its subscription to the original source. After that the first subscriber to come in will trigger a new subscription to the `source`, which you should craft so that it fetches the latest data and re-initializes a polling cycle every 15s.